# Saving datamodels with API O MAT

Tags: iphone, mobile, backend, apiomat

I'm building my app with a backend as a service from https://www.apiomat.org, downloaded the SDK and saved some models. Everything works great, but I do not understand why after saving the model the SDK does a load afterwards. This opens another connection, and I think this is unnecessary. Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server computes some values in addition to these send by the client. These are e.g. the timestamp of creation, the creator and links to references objects.

After the first save, the apiomat SDK uses link returned and loads the complete object from server again to fetch these values. Without the load method, you would not have access to e.g. your references objects.